# Camunda migrate already finished process instances

Tags: process, migration, camunda

following scenarion:

I had a BPM proces in Camunnda, lets say "pv1" (processversion1). On that version I had started new instances which went through the complete process and were finished.

Lets say the process has changed a little bit and the new process version "pv2" exists. Can I migrate the finished instances from process version 1 to an activity of the new version 2? I have read that you can migrate process instances that were at a certain activity at a process to some activity on the new process. But can you also migrate already finished process instances to an activity of the new process version?

Answer (score 1):

You can start a new process instance on version 2, copying the data over, and use process instance modification to move the state / token to the desired activity. This would give you the option to "continue" the completed instance while leaving the completed audit records intact.